# Insert only date to table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, insert, type-conversion

How to insert only `date` into `date` column?

I tried with `cast('11-DEC-1999' as DATE)`

but I got error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: This expression didn't generate any error on my server (SQL Server 2008 R2). Something to do with locale settings, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Just use '2012-02-14', should be fine.  No conversion needed.

Here's a list of acceptable alpha formats: ripped from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

```
Apr[il] [15][,] 1996 

Apr[il] 15[,] [19]96 

Apr[il] 1996 [15]

[15] Apr[il][,] 1996 

15 Apr[il][,][19]96 

15 [19]96 apr[il]

[15] 1996 apr[il]

1996 APR[IL] [15]

1996 [15] APR[IL]
```

You can specify date data with a month specified as the full month name. For example, April or the month abbreviation of Apr specified in the current language; commas are optional and capitalization is ignored.

Here are some guidelines for using alphabetical date formats:

Enclose the date and time data in single quotation marks ('). For languages other than English, use N'

Characters that are enclosed in brackets are optional.

If you specify only the last two digits of the year, values less than the last two digits of the value of the two digit year cutoff configuration option are in the same century as the cutoff year. Values greater than or equal to the value of this option are in the century that comes before the cutoff year. For example, if two digit year cutoff is 2050 (default), 25 is interpreted as 2025 and 50 is interpreted as 1950. To avoid ambiguity, use four-digit years.

If the day is missing, the first day of the month is supplied.

The SET DATEFORMAT session setting is not applied when you specify the month in alphabetical form.

Answer (score 1):

You want the CONVERT function, where you can specify the input format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Specify month as int and after that fetch date  from it

```
       DateTime dt=new DateTime(11,12,1999).Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT (date, '11-DEC-1999') that should help.